# Merge two or more blender files with the same model but with different animations?

Tags: animation

I have a a couple of blender files(.fbx files) where the model for each file is the same, however each file has a unique animation. (Examples of files: player_idle.fbx , player_walk.fbx and player_attack.fbx)

Since they have the exact same model. Is there a way to combine each blender file into a single blender file with all of the animations from every blender file?

Sorry, but I'm quite new to blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a blendfile and import all the .fbx. and save it
2. Open the master blend file. (the one where all animations are supposed to go).
3. Click on File -> Append
4. Choose the blendfile you created earlier containing all the .fbx.
5. Choose the 'folder' Action - Inside are all animations that were imported. Hopefully they have useful names.
6. Press A to select all and Append.
7. Import the main model into your .Blend.
8. Open an Action Editor and select the action you want to use with your selected object.
9. Just for safety check the Fake user icon for each animation.
   [image]
   Now you can switch, combine, select or even export to Unity etc. between your actions.

Btw. an FBX can store more than 1 animation. Usually you wouldn't store the same mesh several times, but once with multiple animations appended, or one fbx for each animation, with the mesh in a separate file.

Comment: Thanks, but some questions. 

It seems they do not have useful names. I got armature.001 and armature.002 etc. Do you know where I can change these to meaningful names? Do I have to check every fbx file i have before the import step (step 1)?

Also what you said at the end. After I append all the animations and I export to unity, does it carry over the all animations?

Comment: This procedure does not work in blender 2.8.... If you follow the steps exactly and then look at your Action Editor, it will not contain all the animations.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't skip step 9? That should take care of that.

Comment: @Joseph In my screenshot you can see CubeAction next to the marked icon. You can select each action in the action editor and rename it.